# jquery mobile popup not working?

Tags: jquery, mobile, popup

im using jquery mobile. im trying to create a popup. I found this simpel code that should work. http://jquerymobile.com/branches/popup-widget/docs/pages/popup/index.html

I tried the code in the example

```
<a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup">Tooltip</a>

<div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">
    This is a completely basic popup, no options set.
</div>
```

but when I put this in my own code the div will still display and when I click on the button it goes to an other page, instead of a popup. Can someone help me?

Comment: take a look at this, the website itself has something wrong with the popups 
http://jquerymobile.com/branches/popup/docs/pages/popup/index.html

Comment: how did you get there? you're on the wrong page this is the link: http://jquerymobile.com/branches/popup-widget/docs/pages/popup/index.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well ... I've gotten it to work (sample code below, sorry for the muddled string I couldn't get it to display in the code blocks otherwise) ... but I'm wondering how YOU found this page??  This doesn't seem to be part of the latest jQuery Mobile release candidate ... so my guess is that it's not working for you because your JS and CSS references aren't pointing to the files that actually contain the corresponding code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="ui-mobile-rendering">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <title>JQM popup test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet"
            href="http://jquerymobile.com/branches/popup-widget/css/themes/default/jquery.mobile.css"/>
        <script src="http://jquerymobile.com/branches/popup-widget/js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="http://jquerymobile.com/branches/popup-widget/js/"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup">Tooltip</a>
        <div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">This is a completely basic popup, no options set.</div>
        <div>Other</div>
        <div>Random</div>
        <div>Text</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So it's not an official release? I found via google ofcourse. When I only put the script in the head. I went to another page but it was all messed up. Your code did work, but I don't think it will work with multiple pages. If it's not an official release I will need to find an other way to make a popup. You how to?

Comment: Yea ... looks like jQuery Mobile 1.1 has gone from a release candidate to "final", and this feature is not included: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/#/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/index.html ... so you can either use the dialog feature explained at http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/#/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-dialogs.html (but that hides all of the original page's contents and is probably not what you want.  I've been using a plugin that you might find useful, http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/demos2/

Comment: And btw the code I showed should work for multiple pages too ... as long as you're referencing those "unofficial" JS and CSS files

Comment: Just a reminder, if this meets your needs please mark it as an answer, thanks!

Comment: This popup functionality is available in the popup-widget branch of jquery mobile: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/tree/popup-widget

Answer (score 4):

It seems popups are scheduled for 1.2 release (see [this page on github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/3218)).
I think the "branches" in the url page indicates that this page is from the unreleased dev branch of jQuery mobile. If you look at the docs page for the 1.1 release, this feature is not documented.

It can be added to 1.0 by adding either the jquery.mobile.popup.js and css from the previous github link or use the [web-ui-fw project](https://github.com/web-ui-fw/web-ui-) which includes the popup widget and other widgets.

I use web-ui-fw to have popups with jQuery mobile 1.1; this plugin uses "popupwindow" instead of "popup" for the data-rel and data-role

Comment: I tried adding both the .css and the .js, yet it didn't work. Did it work for you?

Comment: yes it works using web-ui-fw-libs.js, web-ui-fw.js and web-ui-fw-widget.css. did you use popupwindow instead of popup for the data-rel and data-role?

Comment: I meant that using the jquery-mobile popup .js/.css didn't work. Using web-ui-fw did work :-).