# jquery mobile popup not working

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jquery mobile popup not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147371/jquery-mobile-popup-not-working)

i am trying to create a simple jquery mobile popup using this code

```
<a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup">popup</a>
    <div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">
        <p>This is a completely basic popup, no options set.</p>
    </div>
```

these scripts i used

```
<script src="../jquery/jquery.mobile-1.1.0/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="jquery/jquery.mobile-1.1.0/css/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../jquery/jquery.mobile-1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

why my popup is not working ? any one can help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

need to use this j query mobile link

```
http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.css
http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.js
```

working for me!!