# Why this jquery mobile example doesn't work?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Can anyone please tell why jquery mobile popup doesn't work in this example?

http://jsfiddle.net/6tebj/1/

I want this text to be appeared as a popup only when the link is clicked...

Comment: Possible duplicate  >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147371/jquery-mobile-popup-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Popup is scheduled for Jquery mobile 1.2. 
And you are loading jquery mobile 1.1 libraries.

Ref: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/3218